# Engine randomly over heated and emptied all coolant

Tags: engine, coolant, audi, a4

So I just picked up an 03 Audi A4 1.8 T Quattro and was driving it around a bit trying to get used to manual.

I had been driving it for the better half of two days, took it up to my mechanic buddy and left and the car was completely fine. On my way home decided to stop at Tim Hortons and went through the drive through.

Car overheated within minutes of idling and completely emptied my coolant reservoir. Put some more in, let it run through the system - now it's got a leak in it when it idles but doesn't leak when it's driving (that I saw)

Leak is coming from almost directly under the reservoir by the water pump. I'm super hoping that's not what it is and someone else here might have a better answer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For starters, cars don't lose all their coolant randomly.  There is a reason and it sounds like you have a pretty good idea where the issue is already.  It's either the water pump itself or one of the hoses connected to the water pump that is leaking.

For a 16 year-old vehicle needing to replace either the water pump or hoses or both would not be unexpected.

I'm not a big fan of coincidences and so my first action would be to return to the mechanic and see if perhaps something they did caused this problem.